# python timer between generated values

Tags: python, timer, counter

My arduino runs constantly a sequence of numbers 6 10 14 20 25.

each number is generated for a period of 5 seconds.

Time between 1st number and 2nd is always the same but time period between e.g. 6 & 10 is different than e.g. 14 & 20.

It runs the sequence in this order:
6 10 14 20 25 6 10 14 20 25 6 10 14 20 25 etc. etc. etc.

The example time [seconds] is e.g.

**6**--2s--**10**--8s--**14**-- x--**20**--12s--**25**--3s--**6**--2s--**10** etc. etc.

You can notice there is 'x' between 14 & 20.

It is because x is a random time from the range(1,100) and it is expected value is 5second.

So, I want to run a timer that counts down from 5 to 1 so it indicates expected time that should take to generate value 20 once value 14 is finished every time I move from value 14 to value 20 and timer should count up if it takes longer than 5 second.

I would like to return timer value if it run less or more than 5 second.

What is the best approach to this problem with python ?

EDIT:

below is my current code but it does not work...

```
import time
import sys

### 'a' represent value return from the function that return current value generated by arduino.
### 'a' should be returned every 500ms BUT I do not know how to read it constantly...
a = myArduino()

#expected time between no.14 and no.20
countdown = 5
#countup if 'a' > 5
countup = 0
expectedtime = 5
overtime = 8
cnt = 0
mycountup = []

while True:
    # how to start the code below IF last value returned by Arduno was 14 and time has just started between 14 and 20?
    time.sleep(1)
    countdown -= 1
    if countdown == 0 and a is not 20:
        countup += 1
    if a == 20:
        cnt += 1
        return mycountup.append((countup,cnt))
```

Comment: can you post your code? maybe you should use a while code to print the counter... or maybe use a sleep() statement.. but your question is kinda confusing

Comment: Do you need to print or output the counter? If not, why not simply count from 0 upwards, sleep 1 second per count, and once your new value "20" arrives, figure out if the counter was <5 or >=5.

Comment: yes, I do. I need to display it while it counts and store its final +/- value in db as well but let's skip that part about saving in into db because I know how to do it. thanks

Comment: Edit: I have added my code.